# TypeError: $(...).jqzoom is not a function in firebug

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I try use jqzoom javascript, but doesn't work.In firebug appears this error TypeError: $(...).jqzoom is not a function.I downloaded  and loaded javascripts.The code is:

```
<script src="{base_url()}assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{base_url()}assets/js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{base_url()}assets/css/jquery.jqzoom.css" >

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                      
        $('.xxx').jqzoom();  
    });
</script> 

{foreach $items as $item}
<div class="item_details">
  <a class="xxx" href="{base_url()}assets/image/{$item->code}/{$item->name}"><img  id="img_details" src="{base_url()}assets/image/{$item->code}/{$item->name}"></a>
</div>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: The obvious question is did you put `jquery.jqzoom-core.js` in the assets/js directory so it can be loaded properly?

Comment: i put the javascripts in assets/js

Answer (score 2):

```
download and load 
<script src=".../jquery-1.6.js"></script>
```

Comment: It work now! scripts not work with library jquery-1.9.0.min.js ?!.with jquery-1.6.js work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use `zoom()` instead of `jqzoom()`